# doOnSubscribe gets called on main thread

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

After reading multiple blog posts and documentation, I came to the conclusion that following `doOnSubscribe` will be executed on a worker thread:

```
Observable.just(1)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> Log.d("Testing", "Testing")) // Shouldn't this be on worker thread?
            .subscribe();
```

But after debugging, I see `doOnSubscribe` is executed on main thread. I thought `doOnSubscribe` is similar to other operators and hence has similar threading behavior when coupled with `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`.

What am I missing? How can I move `doOnSubscribe` execution to background thread?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`subscribeOn` and `observeOn` have no effect on `doOnSubscribe` because the connection between operators are established on the caller thread in order to support immediate cancellation. You have to defer the subscription to a `doOnSubscribe` in some way, e.g.:

```java
Observable.defer(() ->
    Observable.just(1)
    .doOnSubscribe(s -> Log.d("Testing", "Testing"))
)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.subscribe();
```

or

```
Observable.just(1)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.flatMap(v ->
    Observable.just(1)
    .doOnSubscribe(s -> Log.d("Testing", "Testing"))
)
.subscribe()
```

Comment: hi @akarnokd. I'm still a bit confused with ```doOnSubscribe```, could you please see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818045/if-it-safe-to-have-blocking-operation-inside-flatmap-mapper-function

Answer (score 5):

By default `doOnSubscribe` executes on the current thread. To change the thread in which `doOnSubscribe` is executed put `subscribeOn` below it.

```
 Observable.just(1)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("doOnSubscribe thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName())) //IO thread
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(s -> {
                System.out.println("subscribing thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());//Computation thread
            });
Thread.sleep(100);
```