# doOnSubscribe is called on IO thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
checkZipCode.exec(it)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSubscribe {
        Timber.d("Main thread: ${Looper.getMainLooper().isCurrentThread}")
        view.showLoading(true)
    }
    .doOnDispose { view.showLoading(false) }
    .flatMapMaybe { isZipValid ->
        if (isZipValid) {
            userModel.zipCode = it.toString()
            saveUser.exec(userModel)
            autoSelectCityIfSingle.exec()
        } else {
            // TODO: Should show error here?
            Maybe.empty()
        }
    }
    .subscribe(...)
```

Logs are: `Main thread: false`

I thought that `doOnSubscribe` is called on the latest scheduler above it. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `doOnSubscribe` is executed on the same thread with `subscribe()`.

I had problems because subscribe() was called on I/O thread.

Answer (score 2):

The subscription execution path isn't really an emission that `observeOn` acts upon. See 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075574/doonsubscribe-gets-called-on-main-thread). If you really want to have something occur on the main thread in that spot in your chain, perhaps you can flatMap in another `Observable` that would do something within its `doOnSubscribe` (since that will occur on the emission thread, which is the main thread here).