# If it safe to have blocking operation inside flatMap { ... } mapper function?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'd like to organize a thread barrier: given a single lock object, any thread can obtain it and continue thread's chain further, but any other thread will stay dormant on the same lock object until the first thread finishes and releases the lock.

Let's express my intention in code (log() simply prints string in a log):

```java
val mutex = Semaphore(1)  // number of permits is 1

source
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())  // any unbound scheduler (io, newThread)
.flatMap {
    log("#1")
    mutex.acquireUninterruptibly()
    log("#2")
    innerSource
       .doOnSubscribe(log("#3"))
       .doFinally {
          mutex.release()
          log("#4")
       }
}
.subscribe()
```

It actually works well, i can see how multiple threads show log "#1" and only one of them propagates further, obtaining lock object **mutex**, then it releases it and i can see other logs, and next threads comes into play. OK

But sometimes, when pressure is quite high and number of threads is greater, say 4-5, i experience DEADLOCK:

Actually, the thread that has acquired the lock, prints "#1" and "#2" but it then **never** print "#3" (so **doOnSubscribe()** not called), so it actually stops and does nothing, not subscribing to **innerSource** in **flatMap**. So all threads are blocked and app is not responsive at all.

My question - is it safe to have blocking operation inside **flatMap**? I dig into **flatMap** source code and i see the place where it internally subscribes:

```java
if (!isDisposed()) {
    o.subscribe(new FlatMapSingleObserver<R>(this, downstream));
}
```

Is it possible that thread's subscription, that has acquired lock, was disposed somehow?

Comment: Makes no sense given that `Flowable` has backpressure and you can limit the concurrency on `flatMap`.

Comment: let me clarify a bit: it's not a source that emits too quickly. It's actually many different places in different threads that can call this method, that assembles the chain with **source**->**flatMap**->**innerSource** and subscribes on it.

Comment: what is the use case for this over using making it single threaded, regradless of calling thread i.e `val scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())` .... `source.subscribeOn(scheduler)....`

Comment: yes, probably subscribeOn() directive is excessive

Comment: I put it here because the enclosing function, that is called from different threads, could be also called from threads that reside in `Schedulers.computation()` pool, and since this function involves some I/O operations, it's unsafe,  (possible same-pool deadlock, see more here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116679/avoiding-same-pool-deadlocks-when-using-flowable-in-reactive-extensions)). I just wanted to exclude same-pool deadlock from the possible causes. Or maybe i'm wrong i still have same-pool deadlock

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` second parameter `maxConcurrency` and set it to 1, so it does what you want without manually locking

Comment: SingleFlatMap does not support maxConcurrency since there is only one upstream source. I'm not using a hot source to emit some values that is then subscribed on and used concurrently. I have some function that is called from different threads, that function operates with Singles and does some work, emits single value and then either continues innerSource or blocks waiting for the lock.

Comment: Ok, instead of creating Single for each caller, can you create Processor and make it hot observable, so that all callers use the same stream?

Comment: I'm not sure i can, because there is some annoyance: let's say the code above, except of `subscribe()` call is a body of some method, say `triggerSource()`. This is not called standalone, but it's part of the chain:

```
triggerSource()
    .flatMap { otherSource }
    .subscribe()
```

each thread has some work to do, and it should preliminary call `triggerSource()` and wait for it's results, then proceeds the chain. So, the main job requires `triggerSource()` to be done, and it may block until another thread finishes it's `triggerSource()` part (and proceed it's own chain further).